# A, B and C are matrices. Prove that $A^{T}AB = A^{T}AC$ iff AB = AC

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$, and $C \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$. Show that $A^{T}AB = A^{T}AC$ iff $AB=AC$.

**What I have done so far**: The direction where I assume $AB=AC$ is trivial. So far, I want to claim that if $A^{T}AB = A^{T}AC$ holds for all $B$ and $C$, then A^{T}A must be a full rank matrix. The reason I suspect this is if $AB \neq AC$ and $A^{T}AB = A^{T}AC$, I would have at least one column of $B$ and $C$, say $b_i$ and $c_i$, such that $Ab_i \neq Ac_i$, but $A^{T}Ab_i = A^{T}Ac_i$. This isn't really too formal, but it gives me some intuition as to why I expect this result to be true.

Comment: I'd try to show that $A^TA$ and $A$ have the same rank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
$$
A^T(AB-AC)=0\qquad\Rightarrow \qquad\\
(B-C)^TA^T(AB-AC)=(AB-AC)^T(AB-AC)=0.
$$

Comment: so are you saying that since $\langle (AB-AC)x,(AB-AC)x\rangle = 0$ for all $x$ that $AB=AC$?

Comment: @Bobo One can do it via that as $\langle (AB-AC)x,(AB-AC)x\rangle =\|(AB-AC)x\|^2$. If it is zero then $(AB-AC)x=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: <v,v> = 0 iff v =0. Thus every x is in the Null Space of AB-AC. Thus AB-AC = 0.

Comment: @Bobo Another way is to take the trace $$\operatorname{trace}((AB-AC)^T(AB-AC))=\|AB-AC\|_{\text{frobenius}}^2=0.$$